# How to pass the value of a radio button to another form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have put Two date Time pickers (dtpStartdate and dtpEndDate), Two Two Combo boxes (cmbStartDate and cmbEndDate) and a radio button(rbStartHalfDay) to a windows form.
Then I wanted to pass values of those items when click "Apply" button. I've written codes for that like this.

```
    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmLeaveRequestConfirmation frm = new frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(dtpStartdate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value, cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex.ToString() );
        frm.ShowDialog();

    }
```

In next form (frmLeaveRequestConfirmation) I've written following code get values wich passing by previous form)

```
    public frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, string SDFH, string EDFH)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblStartDateInfo.Text = SDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"); ;
        if (SDate == EDate)
        {
            //some codes are here               

        }
```

This codes worked fine for dateTime pickers and combo boxes. Then I tried to pass the value of radio button also, using the same method.

//form 1 (frmLeaveRequest)

```
    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmLeaveRequestConfirmation frm = new frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(dtpStartdate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value, cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), rbStartHalfDay.Checked.ToString() );
        frm.ShowDialog();

    }
```

//form 2 (frmLeaveRequestConfirmation)

```
    public frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, string SDFH, string EDFH, string RBHD)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblStartDateInfo.Text = SDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"); ;
        if (SDate == EDate)
        {
         //some codes are here                
        }
```

}

But now it shows an error. please somebody give me the correct code for passing the value of radio button to 2nd form. (My 2nd problem is I can't called to the radio button from my 2nd form, even I set the modifier as public.)

Comment: what is the error ? you want to get "True/False" as `String` ?

Comment: What is the error? As for your 2nd problem mark it `static` though it is not usual to make controls static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion , you should pass your radio button value as `Boolean` .

```
frmLeaveRequestConfirmation frm = 
new frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(dtpStartdate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value,   
cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(),   
rbStartHalfDay.Checked);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

and in your second form ,

```
public frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(  
DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, string SDFH, string EDFH, Boolean RBHD)
{
   ......
```

Comment: Thanks. Now Its works fine. Thank you and every one who answered me quickly. :)

Answer (score 2):

first of all why do you want to parse the checked flag of the radio button from bool to string? Is there any reason? If the radio button is not null you shout get the correct value of it.

So what you can do is something like that:

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmLeaveRequestConfirmation frm = new frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(dtpStartdate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value, cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), rbStartHalfDay.Checked );
    frm.ShowDialog();

}
```

and in the second form:

```
public frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, string SDFH, string EDFH, bool RBHD)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lblStartDateInfo.Text = SDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy"); ;
    if (SDate == EDate)
    {
     //some codes are here                
    }
}
```

To your second question, do you need to set the radio button from the other form? Why don't you add a property to get the information after the frm.ShowDialog() from the frmLeayveRequestConfirmation? Like that:

```
public GetButtonIsChecked { get; private set; }
// something like constructor
private void someMethod(bool isChecked) 
{
    GetButtonIsChecked = isChecked;
}
```

And int the other Class wherer you call the form you do this:

```
    private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmLeaveRequestConfirmation frm = new frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(dtpStartdate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value, cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex.ToString(), rbStartHalfDay.Checked );
    frm.ShowDialog();
    this.rbStartHalfDay.Checked = frm.GetButtonIsChecked;
}
```

Maybe this will solve your problem at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use strings to pass integer and boolean values. Make your second form raising [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983610%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) if you want to notify first form that something happened:

```
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

public frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, 
                                   int startDayIndex, int endDayIndex, 
                                   bool isHalfDayStart)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lblStartDateInfo.Text = startDate.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");

    if (startDate == endDate)
    {
       // some codes are here
    }
}

// When something happened (e.g. user clicked a button)
private void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SomethingHappened != null)
       SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

And create form this way:

```
void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmLeaveRequestConfirmation frm = 
      new frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(dtpStartdate.Value, dtpEndDate.Value, 
                                      cmbStartDate.SelectedIndex, 
                                      cmbEndDate.SelectedIndex,
                                      rbStartHalfDay.Checked);

    frm.SomethingHappened += RequestConfirmation_SomethingHappened;
    frm.ShowDialog();
}

void RequestConfirmation_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // check radiobutton
    rbStartHalfDay.Checked = true;
}
```

NOTE: Use PascalNames for class names and methods. Use camelCase for method parameter names.

Comment: Side note - if you need to pass some data with event, then you can use `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate and create custom EventArgs class to pass data. Or you can simply use `Action<T>` delegate for event. E.g. `public event Action<int> SomethingHappened;` will pass integer value to handler of event

Comment: Thanks. Now Its works fine. Thank you and every one who answered me quickly. :)

Comment: @ThilinaSandunsiri welcome :) another note - instead of passing selected index I think you need to pass selected value, which makes much more sense for second form

Comment: Really I learned some new things from you @Sergey. Itz very valuable for me cause I'm new to C# :)

Answer (score 1):

To transfering values between Forms you can use Form's Constructor.
For example I want to send the boolean value of RadioBtn1 from Form1 to Form2.

```
    public partial class Form2 (bool Value) 
    {
        //Codes
    }

    public partial class Form1 () 
    {
        //Codes

        new Form2(RadioBtn1.Checeked).ShowDialog();
     }
```